# Confusion with how variables are used in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and came across the JS code in which analogy of JS'stop watch object was implemented. Here is the code:

```
function Stopwatch() { 
  let startTime, endTime, running, duration = 0;

  this.start = function() {
    if (running) 
      throw new Error('Stopwatch has already started.');

    running = true; 

    startTime = new Date();
  };

  this.stop = function() {
    if (!running) 
      throw new Error('Stopwatch is not started.');

    running = false; 

    endTime = new Date();

    const seconds = (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000;
    duration += seconds; 
  };

  this.reset = function() { 
    startTime = null;
    endTime = null;
    running = false; 
    duration = 0; 
  };

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'duration', {
    get: function() { return duration; }
  });
}
```

I would like to ask some questions on the above code. The first question is when we use "running" variable in start method's if statement, does the value of "running" converted from being undefined(by default since it was not given a value) to true? The second question, after if statement in start method why running was assigned to true. The third question, since running was assigned to true in start method Is its value changed globally as well? Or globally the value of "running" remains undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...when we use "running" variable in start method's if statement, does the value of "running" converted from being undefined(by default since it was not given a value) to true?

`undefined` is a *falsy* value: It coerces to `false` when used as a boolean, as it is in `start`. The falsy values are `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, and of course, `false`. All other values are *truthy* (including `"0"` and `"false"`, which sometimes surprises people).

> The second question, after if statement in start method why running was assigned to true.

Because the body of the `if (running)` statement isn't run, because `if (running)` is false.

> The third question, since running was assigned to true in start method Is its value changed globally as well?

There is only one `running` variable in the code, which isn't global, but is accessible by all code within the `Stopwatch` function (even after `Stopwatch` returns). So setting it `true` in `start` means it's then `true` throughout the code in `Stopwatch`. (`stop` sets to to `false` again.)

So assume you've just created an instance of `Stopwatch`. When you call `start`:

1. `if (running) throw...` doesn't `throw` because `running` is `undefined`, which is falsy.
2. `running = true;` sets `running` to `true`. There's only one copy of `running` (per `Stopwatch` instance) so all the other code within `Stopwatch` sees that one variable's current value.
3. `startTime = new Date();` saves the start date/time in `startTime`. Like `running`, there's only one of these variables (per `Stopwatch` instance).

If you then called `start` again, `if (running) throw...` would `throw`, because `running` is `true` now.

Later, if you call `stop`:

1. `if (!running) throw...` doesn't `throw` because `running` is `true`.
2. `running = false;` sets `running` to `false`.
3. `endTime = new Date()` sets `endTime` to the current date/time.
4. `const seconds = (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000;` determines the time in seconds between when `start` and `stop` were called.
5. `duration += seconds` adds `seconds` to the existing value in `duration`. `duration` starts out at `0`, but if you do `start`/`stop` and then `start`/`stop` again, it will record the total duration of both timers.

Comment: thank you Mr.Crowder for your kind answer,  if you remember, I am that nagger who asked you so many questions lately)). I am afraid I have a question to ask you kindly. When I change the value of "running" in start method, why do I still get "undefined". Here is the code: let running;

function start(){
    running=true;
}

alert(running);

Comment: @user11807902 - In that example, nothing ever calls `start`, so the code within `start` doesn't run, and `running` is never given a new value. Compare that with: `let running; function start(){ running=true; } alert(running); start(); alert(running);` The first alert would show you `undefined`, the second one would show you `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables have lexical scope, so all of the variables defined on line 2 are available throughout function Stopwatch.

Javascript does a lot of type coercion of variables, especially in evaluating conditions. In javascript, the '!' (not) operator returns a boolean based on how the variable that it's operating on coerces.

When the function starts, running is declared, but not initialized, so javascript initialized it to `undefined`. `undefined` coerces to `false`, so, `!undefined === !false === true`.

In the start function, `running` is set to true so that future checks of `!running` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript all the variables are populated with undefined until they are getting a value.

In your example variables *startTime, endTime, running* have undefined values when the an instance of Stopwatch is created (they are global in each instance).

**start** method checks the state of the `running` variable and then if it has not got the value of **true** then it updates the value and starts the stopwatch by setting the `startTime` variable.

**stop** method examines the state of `running` and ensures if it has the proper value (to check if the start method has been called before).  Then, it calculates the duration and sets the value into `duration` variable.

Finally, **reset** method, simply resets all the values of variables.